# Constituency Tests

Tags: grammar, constituents, constituency

I had a test and the question was to test the underlined part for constituency; however, I got confused because I used the test of deletion, but I found the sentence ungrammatical, so my answer was that the underlined part is not a constituent. My friends applied the pseudo-clefting test and found that the sentence is grammatically fine.

The sentence is:

> My mother told me *to pick up the dry cleaning* on my way home.

The part in italic is what we were required to test.

This is my answer after I applied the deletion test:

> *My mother told me - on my way home.

My friends' answer with pseudo-clefting applied:

> What my mother told me is to pick up the dry cleaning.

So I want to ask the following:

1. Could a specific structure or sting of words be a constituent when we fail to apply one of the tests on?
2. Is my answer wrong?
3. Are there specific tests for each structure depending on its type or category? For example can we always apply It-cleft to test the subject?

Answer (score 5):

To quote Adger's syntax textbook:

> It is important to note that when these tests are successful then what you
> have is an **argument** that a particular sequence forms a constituent, rather than proof that it does. It is even more important to notice that when one of these tests fails, we cannot conclude that the sequence is not a constituent, we can only conclude that there is no evidence that it is.

The problem is, there's no single test that's both necessary and sufficient to show that something is a constituent. For example, it's usually taken as an axiom that single words (or rather lexical items) are always constituents. But they can easily fail all sorts of tests:

- The cat is hungry.
- *The is hungry.
- *Cat is what the is hungry.
- *What the is hungry? Cat.
- *The it is hungry.

(In particular, this shows that you can't generally move or delete an NP out of a DP, and pronouns replace DPs, not NPs. These are separate rules of the language.)

The advice I generally give is to apply several different constituency tests, rather than just one. Try at least one movement test and one substitution test and see what happens.

Comment: Hmm. Devil's advocate: You nearly always *can* delete the 'NP' in a 'DP'. You more or less only can't if the D is *the, a, every* (i.e. if it's an article). For all the very many other D's you can! Devil's devil's advocate: aren't pronouns intransitive D's?

Comment: @Araucaria-him For the first one, true, but I tend to think of articles as the most common determiners. For the second one—yes, but thus aren't they also DPs, since they don't have any unmet c-selections?

Comment: Yes, I think every pro-X must be an XP too. Maybe by definition? [With 'pronoun' being a misnomer as they are really pro-D's].

Comment: Only if you go to a certain type of church. The rest of us still believe that NPs exist and DPs are superstition.

Comment: @jlawler Very true, but then there's the other type of church that thinks dependency is more important than constituency and so on and so forth. I don't want to go too in-depth on the options since it sounds like OP is a beginner.

Comment: From my experience, beginners prefer NPs and VPs to X-bars.

Comment: @jlawler I'm not an X-bar theorist, but I do think there's at least a good case for traditional NP's being DP's--for very different reasons, though. It seems to me that many of the arguments for auxiliary verbs being heads apply to D's being heads. (And that many of the arguments against D's being heads could equally apply to auxiliaries not being heads)

Comment: Auxiliary verbs are just verbs that been bleached of meaning and assigned slave roles in constructions. Ditto articles. But stacked auxiliaries just produce a [vp v [vp v [vp v ... ]]] structure; why do any different for NPs? The head of a verb phrase is a verb, of whatever flavor. Determiners are usually old pronouns anyway. See my [VP guide](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf),

Comment: @Araucaria. The evidence in favor of DPs is weak. The issue you point to, i.e. determiners are heads in the same manner that auxiliaries are heads, does not hold up to scrutiny. Most modern textbooks that assume DPs do so without justifying the assumption. Adger's discussion of the issue is, for instance, lacking; he simply assumes DPs on pages 250-255, without much motivation.

Comment: @TimOsborne Well, I'm undecided but my motivation is completely different from the generativists'. It starts with the arguments in [Spinillo](https://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/id/eprint/10101595/1/out.pdf)'s excellent and very readable PhD theses (only recently available online) that there is no meaningful word category determiner/determinative in English. Similar but different arguments to Spinillo's are made by [Dick Hudson 1999](https://dickhudson.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/funccat.pdf). Then if pronouns and D's are N's, it's a shorter jump to the Determiner being the Head, and the 'nominal'

Comment: @TimOsborne ... the dependent.

Comment: @Araucaria. Thanks for your response. I extensively refute Hudson's arguments in favor of DPs [here](https://akjournals.com/view/journals/2062/68/3/article-p274.xml). His argument about determiners being transitive pronouns oversimplifies and overlooks the variation in the data. If you would like an accessible discussion of the arguments for and against NP and DP, see the Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner_phrase#:~:text=%20In%20the%20example%20determiner%20phrases%20below%2C%20the,each%20little%20dog%2C%20no%20dog%20%28quantifiers%29%20More%20) , which I wrote.

Answer (score 3):

The test question (sentence) may be problematic. The string "My mother told me to pick up the dry cleaning on my way home" has two analyses, and two semantic interpretations. The interpretations are probably more obvious. One is that we don't know when or where you mother told you this, but that thing that you are supposed to do is "pick up the dry cleaning on (your) way home". The other is that we don't know when she wants you to pick it up, but it was when you were on your way home that she told you this. This may or may not relate to different constituencies (though I don't know of a theory that bothers to have a semantics, and that only allows one of the two syntactic structures). Generally speaking, constituency tests only work if the semantic interpretation is held constant.

Your answer is wrong by dint of the fact that you assert that "*My mother told me-on my way home" is ungrammatical. But it *is* grammatical, and you can use various substitutions to convince yourself of that ("My mother spoke to me on my way home; my mother saw me on my way home; a cat bit me on my way home"). I assume that the instructor had in mind only the interpretation that the picking up would take place when you are on your way home, and did no consider the interpretation that the telling was on the way home.

There are two constituencies to consider:

> My mother told me [to pick up the dry cleaning on my way home]
>
> My mother told me [to pick up the dry cleaning] on my way home

The output "What my mother told me is to pick up the dry cleaning" does not directly correspond to either, also I find that output to be a bit sketchy though for purposes of the exam one might claim that it is grammatical ("...told me *to do*..."). What you want is

> What my mother told me (to do) on my way home is [to pick up the dry cleaning]
>
> What my mother told me (to do) is [to pick up the dry cleaning on my way home]

If only one of these two options were grammatical (using both tests), you would have evidence for a single constituency. Instead, you have contradictions – evidence for two constituencies, i.e. syntactic ambiguity.

It is possible that the correct answer per the instructor is "there's a contradiction, therefore there are two constituencies". I guess you'll find out when you get the results.